# For what values of $a$ will $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n}{1 + a^{2n}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

My task is this:

Find the values s.t. $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n}{1 + a^{2n}}$$ Converges.

My work so far:

We observe that in order for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n}{1 + a^{2n}}$ to converge, $\frac{a^n}{1 + a^{2n}}$ needs to converge, and be decrasing. For any $n$ this will be an infinite geometric series with $a_1 = a^n$ and $r = -a^{2n}$ so we obtain following:$$a^{2n}<1 \to \ln(a) < \frac{\ln(1)}{2n}\to e^{\ln(a)}<e^0\to a<1.$$

Now at this point I'm stuck, starting to dubt my reasoning because the answer to this riddle according to my book is that the series converges $\forall a\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{\pm 1 \}$. So I need a little help from the community, point out my mistakes and improve my reasoning.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are we assuming $a \geq 0$ ?

Comment: argue all possibe cases with ratio test. plugging -1 and +1 for $a$ make direct arguments with the series itself.

Comment: Notice that $f(a)=\frac{a^n}{1+a^{2n}}$ fulfills $f(a)=f(1/a)$.

Comment: Intuitively, for $|a|>1$, the fractions are close to $a^{-n}$, as $1$ becomes neglectible compared to $a^{2n}$. For $|a|<1$, they are close to $a^n$, as $a^{2n}$ becomes neglectible compared to $1$. In both cases, convergence is that of a geometric series. (There's also the shortcut by @JackD'Aurizio.) And the cases $a=\pm1$ are obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a series is convergent for any $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1,1\}$. Since
$$ f_n(a) = \frac{a^n}{1+a^{2n}} $$
fulfills $f_n(a)=f_n\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)$, it is enough to study the convergence for $a\in [-1,1]$.

We obviously do not have convergence at the endpoints, but for every $a\in(-1,1)$
$$ \forall n,\qquad |f_n(a)| \leq C\,|a|^n $$ 
is enough to grant convergence. Moreover,
$$ \forall a\in(-1,1),\quad \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{a^n}{1+a^{2n}} = \frac{\vartheta_3(0,a)^2-1}{4} $$
where $\vartheta_3$ is a [Jacobi theta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html).

Comment: What is so special about series fulfilling $f_n(a)=f_n(\frac{1}{a})$ and how is it helpful in studying the convergence?

Comment: @KushalBhuyan: that property is not so crucial, it is just a shortcut to study the convergence over an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ without loss of generality, as explained by Yves Daoust in the comments, too.